# Protecting Linux systems from symlink attacks

Tags: linux, security, symlink

Linux-based systems are vulnerable to symlink race attacks from unprivileged UID processes. For *example*, a PHP process on a shared hosting can create a symlink to /etc/passwd in a directory where Apache httpd will serve it to anybody on the Internet. For other examples of symlink-related issues, see

https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=linux+symlink+race

I'd like some way to protect all Linux systems (of various versions) from those suspect processes creating malicious symlinks.

There are some partial solutions out there, but usually they involve custom patching of the Linux kernel (which is a lot of work and a drag on update process) or they are not sufficiently restrictive. There is Kees Cook's patch to Linux in versions 3.6 and higher

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=800179c9b8a1e796e441674776d11cd4c05d61d7

but it is not present in all earlier Linux versions and it protects only from some symlink issues, not necessarily all of them (such as creating symlinks in non-sticky bit directories, which is still a problem).

**What are some universal solutions to symlink race vulnerabilities applicable to all common Linux systems, from version 2.6.26 on?**

One thing that comes to mind is setting up a global rule that prevents high UID users from ever creating a symlink. For some deployments (shared hosting), such restriction may be acceptable.

**What is the easiest way to ban users from creating symlinks on systems with Linux kernel >=2.6.26?** (symlinks however need to be supported for more privileged users, including root)

**Which of these: SELinux, Seccomp-bpf, Apparmor is best suited for setting up such a restriction?**

Comment: `chroot` jail?...

Comment: @Fox Symlinks have to be supported to have a functioning Linux system, I only want to restrict a subset of unix users.

Comment: @Attie unfortunately that is not enough, since the user process can still create a bait symlink to some absolute path in the chrooted root, and other non-chrooted processes could fall for that bait (PHP creates symlink to its local /etc/passwd in its chroot but httpd outside the chroot will serve the global /etc/passwd).

Comment: @sourcejedi thanks. Constraining a shell would be "unusual" and hard to do, but my focus in the question is on PHP and possibly other suspect processes initiated by unknown Internet clients. On a shared hosting server, PHP process should not be able to read the global list of unix users and their settings, and it should not be fully POSIX-capable.

Comment: There is `/proc/sys/fs/protected_symlinks` which prevents some of the attacks, but it requires Linux >=3.6.

Comment: @domen Yes, it even is present on Debian 7 with 3.2.0-6, but as stated in the question, I'm looking for a more robust and more universal solution.

Comment: @sourcejedi alright, I've added some remark on the use-case.

Comment: @JánLalinský my `disable_functions` answer seems too trivial, therefore I still think you want a stronger example.

Comment: @PhilipCouling do you mean the CVEs? Those are just other examples. My main example is about putting a symlink to /etc/passwd to some httpd-served directory.

Comment: @PhilipCouling both where the PHP-generated symlink is and what it points to is important. I want to prevent random client on the Internet from reading system configuration files. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, so put apache in a chroot... then no matter what symlink it is given, it can't serve a system file.  Also configure apache properly.  You should configure it to refuse to serve all files and then make specific exceptions for specific directories.  Apache is aware of symlinks and will apply its configuration accordingly.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Apache configuration is powerless against the race attacks, this is documented on Apache website. If the PHP process changes destination of the symlink frequently, Apache may be tricked to serve content outside the permitted directories. Running Apache in chroot does not seem to help, because it has to be able to read global /etc/passwd so even in chroot it would have access to the same content and could be tricked to serve it.

Comment: "_httpd outside the chroot will serve the global /etc/passwd_" my point was really to put `httpd` in a jail as well... that way `/etc/passwd` doesn't / shouldn't exist from its point of view.

Comment: @Attie, I may be able to do that for /etc/passwd, but I want to prevent serving other files as well, such as the Apache main configuration, list of hosted domains, configuration in etc, etc. Chroot does not prevent Apache from serving all sensitive files. That's why I am asking about symlinks, they can point to any well known path and I can't hide them all from Apache.

Comment: @JánLalinský you mean something like this https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_unixd.html#chrootdir Honestly symlinks are not the only way to trick a program to read / modify the wrong thing.  This is what `chroot` was created for and its why most comprehensive servers such as openssh and apache contain chroot facilities.

Comment: @PhilipCouling no I meant documentation for FollowSymlinks and SymlinksIfOwnerMatch https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html.  What are some other ways to trick a program to read the wrong thing? AFAIK PHP process cannot create file with same path as one already used by a sensitive file.

Answer (score 2):

Preventing Apache from creating symlinks probably doesn't break it.

On *current* Linux, there are two system calls that can create new symlinks: `symlink` and `symlinkat`.

`man systemd.exec` tells us that systemd can install a seccomp filter, to deny certain system calls: `SystemCallFilter=~symlink symlinkat`.  And according to `man systemd.unit`, existing systemd service files can be amended using "drop-in" files e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/nosymlink.conf`.

EDIT: of course if you were running PHP as FastCGI in a separate systemd service, then that is the service you need to amend instead of `httpd`.

There is a massive caveat with this "blocklist" approach:

Upgrading your OS to a new kernel may add support for new system calls.  Unfortunately even the newer `symlinkat()` did not add a flags argument.  Therefore a new system call might need to be added in future, if the behaviour of `symlinkat` needs to be modified in any way.  Ironically, the most likely reason for this is in order to add [AT_BENEATH](https://lwn.net/Articles/767547/) support for `symlinkat`.  This could re-open the "vulnerability", e.g. if newer versions of GNU libc funnel all symlink creation through a new `symlinkat2()` system call.

Comment: And what if a file is created that is in it's binary form a symlink (like a compress TAR with symlinks inside of it)?

Comment: @Serverfrog nothing.

Comment: Thank you, the seccomp way via systemd setting is interesting. Unfortunately, it only works on systems with very recent systemd (it does not work on Centos 7 with systemd 219).

Answer (score 1):

You can use immutable bit option in Linux.

A file with an immutable attribute can not be:

1. Modified
2. Deleted
3. Renamed
4. No soft or hard link created by anyone including root user

Use chattr(check if your OS supports) command to set the attribute.

```
chattr +i file
chattr +i /path/to/filename
```

To list the properties of file wrt attribute bit

```
lsattr /etc/shadow
```

To remove immutable bit:

```
chattr -i file
chattr -i /path/to/filename
```

Comment: it does not prevent *soft* links being created to it. it prevents hard links being created to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ban PHP reading /etc/passwd, then you must already ban it from executing arbitrary commands.

Then you already know how to ban it from calling `symlink()`.

I note that PHP has deprecated and removed "safe mode", and there is still no official usage guidance for [`disable_functions`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions).

Comment: How would I ban PHP from executing arbitrary syscalls? Via seccomp-bpf, or is there something more user-friendly?

Comment: how did you ban it from *executing arbitrary commands* e.g. shell commands that read `/etc/passwd` ?

Comment: I didn't, but the PHP process is restricted from reading /etc/passwd because it runs in chrooted environment where there is no global /etc/passwd. This does not solve the symlink problem though, because Apache isn't running in that chrooted environment and has to be able to read global /etc/passwd.

Comment: @JánLalinský I see, then if there is *no* command you want PHP to be able to execute, you could use one of the recipes for [`disable_functions`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) that disables executing programs, and just add `symlink` and `eio_symlink` to the list of functions.

Comment: @JánLalinský you would need to disable executing programs somehow because otherwise PHP can write an arbitrary program and then execute it :-).

Comment: I know, symlink function in PHP and running /bin/ls is already disabled, I worry more about hacked PHP process which won't respect the PHP setting disable_functions. I do not want to rely on PHP doing my security checks.